# How to decode a charcter encoding

Tags: java, encoding

My application is posting a request through http and gets a response as a String. The string has delimited character of records. When I try to split the records with the delimiter, it is not able to identify as the response string delimiter character is encoded in different format. Is there a way I can convert the response encoded character or identify the encoding type of my response ?

Comment: You will want to show us a typical example of the text you're receiving and the bad output of your program upon processing this text.

Comment: Not sure if you using any out of box http library. Make sure to URL decode the string before you split it.

Comment: I do not know if there is a definitive answer, there are packages like http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/ that try and work out the charset. From my experience they miss the correct encoding more often than they get it correct. If has a very specific format, you could check all the likely encodings and validate the respone with each encoding. Ideally you ensure the character-encoding is sent as well